# delete unwanted directories, error produced is forced on screen

Tags: batch-file

this deletes `.unwanted` directories from qbittorrent downloads. it works great but the esthetic side effect that I can't shake is that it echoes the `file not found` error if none are found.

```
for /f "delims=" %%u in ('dir .unwanted /a:d /b /s') do rmdir /s /q "%%u" 2>nul && if defined v%~n0 echo deleted "%%u"
```

Comment: Redirect the error within the parentheses: `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/AD ".unwanted" 2^>Nul') Do @RD /S/Q "%%A" …`

Comment: @bricktop Read for example [this short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760973/3074564) if you want to know why `2^>nul` must be used instead of `2>nul` as usual in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better idea is to use **`/D /R`** than **`/F`** in the **`For`** loop for **Directories**.  Check **`For /?`** documentation.

```
for /d /r %%u in (.unwanted) do rmdir /s /q "%%u" 2>nul & echo deleted %%u
```

This is assuming you are running this from the directory of execution.
It will only **`echo` when the directory is deleted** without the **`""`**